Sensitivity Labels for Intranet
What are the recommendations (if any) for Microsoft 365 sensitivity labels when it comes to creating intranet sites?
We have 50 departments, each department should have its own hub + about 200 site collections belonging to each hub.
The departments are relatively varied, some collaborating a lot with external users, some not at all. Some working exclusively on the road, some from home office, some always at the office. The company has 50 000+ users.
Is there any published guidance? Anything you guys would recommend to avoid at all cost?
I realize it's a very broad question, and will be grateful for any practical tips specific to intranet. I am aware of general label functionalities, and we also have some implemented, used e.g. for team sites. We do not want to reuse the existing ones.
Note to the Moderator: I am not asking for asking for anyone's opinion :) I am rather looking for a resource similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/intranet-governance
